# Stimul Report : businessObjects doesn't load by showing the report

Tags: stimulsoft

I save the report template :

```
report.Save("C:\\kk.mrt");
```

then I load the saved report and assign it `BusinessObjects` as `Dictionaries`

```
StiReport rptLoad = new StiReport();
rptLoad.RegBusinessObject("Company", repository.GetAll<Company>());
rptLoad.Load("C:\\kk.mrt");
```

`rptLoad.BusinessObjectsStore` contains registered `BusinessObjects` just registered (`Watched` at `RunTime`)  but :

```
rptLoad.Show();
```

- IF there are `Bindings` (Like: `Components.Add(new StiText{Text="{Company.Name}"}`) included in the saved report : THEN

  gets me :  `error CS0103: The name 'Company' does not exist in the current context`
- ELSE IF I have no `Bindings` in saved report : THEN

  `rptLoad.Show();` will show the report , but with no registered `Dictionaries` (As i go to design mode after showing the report I see no `BusinessObjects` in Dictionary).
- And IF I call `rptLoad.Design();` before `rptLoad.Show();` : THEN

the report shows and `Bindings` are OK and I can see `BusinessObjects` in the shown report (in both design and preview mode).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the cause :

```
            rptLoad.Dictionary.Synchronize();
```

should call after `rptLoad.RegBusinessObject("Company", repository.GetAll<Company>());`